# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting - Python

Tags: python

I am messing around trying to learn Python and am working through some examples on https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter14/ - this one is to pull simple weather data.  I am getting an error when running the script that I can't seem to find an answer for...primary, because I am not sure how to ask it, so here goes:

**My Code (from the book)**

```
#! python3
# quickWeather.py - Prints the weather for a location from the command line

import json
import requests
import sys

# Compute location from command line arguments.
if len(sys.argv) < 1:
    print('Usage: quickweather.py location')
    sys.exit()
location = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])

# Todo: Download the json data from OpenWeatherMap.org's API

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=5391811&APPID=5103aa7d5415db6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' % (location)
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

# Load JSON data into Python variable.
weatherData = json.loads(response.text)

w = weatherData['list']
print('Current weather in %s:' % (location))
print(w[0]['weather'][0]['main'], '-', w[0]['weather'][0]['description'])
print()
print('Tomorrow:')
print(w[1]['weather'][0]['main'], '-', w[1]['weather'][0]['description'])
print()
print('Day after tomorrow:')
print(w[2]['weather'][0]['main'], '-', w[2]['weather'][0]['description'])
```

**And My Console Error**

```
rooster@python_tests $ python3 quickWeather.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickWeather.py", line 16, in <module>
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=5391811&APPID=5103aa7d5415db6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' %(location)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

If I remove the % (location) from the url path, console will print the data except for the location, which in this case is San Diego.

I know this is bit of a trivial questions and if I knew more about Python, it would be easy to answer, but now, after 2 hours of messing with it, I am dying to know what the heck is up.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So where in the string should the location be interpolated? You are missing a `%s` placeholder.

Comment: the way that `%` string formatting works is you have to have a `%x` placeholder in your string for each value in your tuple.

Comment: The % is in the first print statement...this book is off a bit (for a beginner) as it doesn't even mention needing an API key, but here is the complete string with my APIKEY ( I can reset later) - the (location) is supposed to grab the city name...just paste this in your browser http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=5391811&APPID=5103aa7d5415db68faab1777de2897ee

Answer (score 0):

The `%` string formatting feature uses *placeholders*; each value interpolated replaces one of those placeholders. You didn't include any placeholder in your string, so Python cannot know where to put the value of `location`.

If you wanted to create a [forecast for a location](http://openweathermap.org/forecast5) you'll need to include a `q=place,country` parameter. The page you link to does exactly that, using a `%s` placeholder:

```
url ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=%s&cnt=3' % (location)
```

Here the `location` string value is slotted into the URL at the `%s` location.

Comment: Ahhh...I think I am getting it...let me experiment real quick and I'll let you know.  Thank you.